# Why string is getting trimmed on using "+" opeartor in printf

Tags: c

I have written following C application:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct Book {
    int a;
    int b;
};

int main() {

    struct Book book;
    book.a = 10;
    book.b = 20;

    printf("The value set for struct a " + book.a);

    return 0;
}
```

I have used `+` inside `printf` expecting it will concatenate the string but instead it is trimming first `10` character and giving the output as following, I know I should use `%d` and pass `book.a` as second argument, **but why `printf` is trimming my string?**

```
set for struct a
```

Comment: The `+` operator does not concatenate strings with integers.

Comment: You're doing pointer-arithmetic, not concatenation.

Comment: A string literal decays to a pointer to its first element. Using operator + on a pointer increments the pointer forward. You can figure out the rest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A string constant in some contexts decays into a pointer to the first element, which is what is happening here.  When you then add an integer value to a pointer it increments the pointer by that many (in the case of a `char *`) bytes.

Since `book.a` is 10, you're adding 10 to the value of the pointer.  So you now have a pointer to the 10th element in the string.  That's what `printf` receives, and that's where it starts printing from.

```
"The value set for struct a"
          ^--- 10th character
```

Answer (score 1):

There are no built-in strings in C, let alone string operators. Null-terminated string literals is where string support ends at the language level; everything else is done in the standard library.

Operator `+` adds number 10 to the value of the *pointer*, to which your string literal is converted. This produces a pointer to the middle of the string, which is what gets printed once `%s` format specifier is applied.

Essentially, this expression

```
"The value set for struct a " + book.a
```

does the same thing as this code:

```
char prtStr[] = "The value set for struct a ";
char *ptrMid = &ptrStr[book.a];
printf("%s", ptrMid);
```

If you want to print `10` after the string, use `%d`, like this:

```
printf("The value set for struct a %d", book.a);
```

Comment: The value added to the pointer is not a character code, it's just an integer.

Comment: @KeithThompson Ah, you are absolutely right, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The string `"The value set for struct a "` is represented as a pointer to the memory that holds a null-terminated array of characters. By adding `book.a` (10) to it, you referred to the tenth element of the buffer, which is `"s"`. What you need is:

```
printf("The value set for struct a %d", book.a);
```